# Как заполнить таблицу html при помощи формы, php?

Tags: php, html

Всем привет, я новичок в php. Не могу понять как заполнить таблицу html при помощи формы.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
        table{
             border:1px solid black; 
             margin-top:30px
        }
        td,tr{
            border:1px solid black;
        }
    </style>

</head>
<body>
<form action="form.php" method="POST">
    A
    <input type="text" name="A">
    B
    <input type="text" name="B">    
    <input type="submit" name="C" value="ok">
</form>
<?
$html="<table>";
$html.="<tr>";
$html.="<td>";
$html.=$_POST['A'];
$html.="</td>";
$html.="<td>";
$html.=$_POST['B'];
$html.="</td>";
$html.="</tr>";
$html.="</table>";
echo $html;
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Делаю так, но понимаю что это не правильно ведь страница обновляется, подскажите как реализовать такую задачу?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Я убрал action="form.php", теперь добавляются значения, в первую строку таблицы, подскажите, пожалуйста, а как тогда добавить еще строчки при помощи этих же полей формы? Я подозреваю что в цикле, но как?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ваш код сейчас работает, если убрать `action="form.php"` из кода. Тогда скрипт будет срабатывать на этой же странице и после нажатия ок появится таблица.

Эта строчка перенаправляет на страницу form.php. А там у Вас, наверное, пусто.

В Ваш код лучше добавить проверку:

```
<?
if($_POST['C']){
    $html="<table>";
    $html.="<tr>";
    $html.="<td>";
    $html.=$_POST['A'];
    $html.="</td>";
    $html.="<td>";
    $html.=$_POST['B'];
    $html.="</td>";
    $html.="</tr>";
    $html.="</table>";
} else {
    $html.="<p>Форма сейчас пуста</p>";
}
echo $html;
?>
```

UPDATE:

Добавить еще строчку - с помощью javascript, формой тут не обойтись. Вот, написал быстро, вроде так должно быть как-то:

```
<form method="POST" name="myForm">
    <input type="text" name="A" />
    <input type="text" name="B" /> 
    <input type="button" value="Добавить строчку" onclick="addNewRow(this.form.A.value, this.form.B.value);" />
</form>
<table id="myTable"></table>

<script>
function addNewRow(val1, val2){
    var tbl = document.getElementById('myTable');
    var tblValue = tbl.innerHTML;
    tbl.innerHTML = tblValue + '<tr><td>'+val1+'</td><td>'+val2+'</td></tr>';
}
</script>
```

Comment: Я убрал action="form.php", теперь добавляются значения, в первую строку таблицы, подскажите, пожалуйста, а как тогда добавить еще строчки при помощи этих же полей формы? Я подозреваю что в цикле, но как?

Comment: Обновил ответ, посмотрите, может так подойдет, у меня работает: http://fisherwoman.ru/index1.php

Comment: Спасибо, огромное!